# Case assignment rules reassigning back to queue

Tags: configuration, assignment-rules

I have a case assignment rule. The case is assigned to the queue based on that and then is subsequently routed to the queue member. But the issue occurs when the case owner clicks on the EDIT button and makes some changes, the case is assigned back to the queue. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Basically you need to add another filter to stop recalculation of the assignment rule. As we know Queue ID starts with 00G and User ID starts with 005. So comparing the OwnerId to make sure if the OwnerId doesn't start with 005 (which means it is not owned by Queue Member), then only run the assignment rule.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like assignment rule is firing again. You need to add another filter which can stop your assignment rule to fire everytime

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Omni-Channel:

1. Add WRONG QUEUE (or whatever your code may be) status to the Case Status field as a choice
2. Set the decline reason in Omni Channel: Omni-Channel>Presence Decline Reason
3. Add your code from #1
4. Add your code from #1 to Default Presence Configuration:  Omni-Channel Settings>Default Presence Configuration